# Objective-C Run while statement for NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, while-loop

So, I compile an NSString of what would be the parameters of the while function I am trying to run... I'll try to elaborate. I am using the code:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [self.badCoords count]; i++) {
    CGFloat off = [[self.badCoords objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    [str appendFormat:@"(y > %.0f || y < %.0f) && ", off+21, off-21];
}
str = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-4];
```

to give me the output string of `(y > 102 || y < 60) && (y > 134 || y < 92) && (y > 116 || y < 74)` or something similar.

I then need to place that string into a while statement, similar to this:

```
while((y > 102 || y < 60) && (y > 134 || y < 92) && (y > 116 || y < 74)) {
    y = [self somethingNew];
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Well I have the app create UI Elements at random Y origins, and need to get them not to overlap.

Answer (score 3):

What you are effectively asking is "how do I dynamically generate code, compile it, then execute it?"

And the answer is;  "You don't".  At least, you don't outside of very specific circumstances and, if you do, you don't do so and expect any kind of reasonable performance.

In this case, it looks like you have a numeric representation of whatever values you need to test.   Best to leave 'em as numbers!   Printing into a string and then trying to parse / compile it back out is a glacially slow pattern (see TCL prior to 2000).

I.e. you would calculate your various limits and then directly use the while() statement.

```
while((y > upperLimit) || (y < lowerLimit) ... etc ...) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you're asking for:

```
float y = initialYValue;
BOOL yInBadRanges = NO;
while (!yInBadRanges) {
    for (NSNumber *coordinate in self.badCoords) {
        CGFloat upperLimit = [coordinate floatValue]+21.0f;
        CGFloat lowerLimit = [coordinate floatValue]-21.0f;
        if (y <= upperLimit && y >= lowerLimit) {
            yInBadRanges = YES
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!yInBadRanges) y = [self somethingNew];
}
```

Note that the way you were originally asking to go about it isn't the way I've done it. It doesn't make sense to convert the conditionals to a formatted string the way you're doing, because you can't use the string as the conditional expression in a while loop that way.

Your comment clarifies your intent just a little, but without more detail it's hard to suggest a specific course of action. My advice would be to think hard about how to do what you're trying to accomplish without being set on a particular way of doing it at the start. There's may be a better algorithm for laying out controls...

(Standard disclaimer applies: I typed this into the answer editor, without running it...)

Comment: @bbum is of course right. The code I've posted does the same kind of thing he suggests.

Answer (score 1):

DDMathParser might do what you're looking for. https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser

Answer (score 0):

You can do some logical tests (defined at runtime) using the NSPredicate class feature.
Have a look on it, it may be what you need.